# How to force @change/@input event to fire whenever user inputs data?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, events, vuejs3

I can use `input DOM element` to upload an image and pass its data to a function like so:

```
<input type="file" @change="myFunction"/>
```

but since the event is `@change`, it only fires when the image data changes. When I want to upload the same image twice, the event doesn't fire. I've tried using the `@input` event instead but it behaves exactly the same, not firing when the same image is uploaded.

Is there any way to upload the same image twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by attaching the `@click` event and then empty the target value `event.currentTarget.value = ''`

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    myClickFunction(e) {
        e.currentTarget.value = '';
    },
    myFunction() {
        console.log('call');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" @click="myClickFunction" @change="myFunction"/>
</div>
```